# grok expression to pull string with in brackets

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Am currently trying to parse log messages using grok. below is the sample message

```
[de4131185bb28bcd5f3019b168106682] [172.69.62.54] [/v2/user.json] Returned lineup_key for user OAuth [ OAuth realm="", oauth_consumer_key="qQRye5YLMtdw2TNmoiayMptwdbW29y3pTlaIj0lx", oauth_token="ArFbNvrxntvYIbA2QArJnCmbGCBQe3P5I1YHX8TX", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="o1DhpgEX7QyCDjDvPceHzJrm7h4%3D", oauth_timestamp="1529081887", oauth_nonce="0C6F8BAC-B3E3-44F3-A3BD-F04CF7815580", oauth_version="1.0" ] : [ MjE2LDI1OA== ]
```

The grok expression being used is below

```
UMSAPPLOGDATA ^\[%{WORD:id}\]\s\[%{IP:ip}\]\s\[%{URIPATHPARAM:uri}\]%{GREEDYDATA:logMessage}
```

Now i want to extract the entire Oauth piece below into separate variable called oauth_parameters.

```
[ OAuth realm="", oauth_consumer_key="qQRye5YLMtdw2TNmoiayMptwdbW29y3pTlaIj0lx", oauth_token="ArFbNvrxntvYIbA2QArJnCmbGCBQe3P5I1YHX8TX", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="o1DhpgEX7QyCDjDvPceHzJrm7h4%3D", oauth_timestamp="1529081887", oauth_nonce="0C6F8BAC-B3E3-44F3-A3BD-F04CF7815580", oauth_version="1.0" ]
```

How can i extend my existing  grok expression for the same.

appreciate you help regarding the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a [custom grok pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_custom_patterns) in the following format,

```
(?<field_name>the pattern here)
```

Your pattern would then be,

```
\buser OAuth (?<outh_parameters>(.*)oauth_version="\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}" ])
```

It will output,

```
{
  "outh_parameters": [
    [
      "[ OAuth realm="", oauth_consumer_key="qQRye5YLMtdw2TNmoiayMptwdbW29y3pTlaIj0lx", oauth_token="ArFbNvrxntvYIbA2QArJnCmbGCBQe3P5I1YHX8TX", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="o1DhpgEX7QyCDjDvPceHzJrm7h4%3D", oauth_timestamp="1529081887", oauth_nonce="0C6F8BAC-B3E3-44F3-A3BD-F04CF7815580", oauth_version="1.0" ]"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: you solution works to me when used in the "http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/"  but when i try to use the same using the python  grok library in the link "https://github.com/garyelephant/pygrok"  it doesnt seem to be working. any idea ?

Comment: thanks for response i was able to  make it work by same python library using custom pattern concept it had.  Am very bad at regex and totally new to Grok.  Can you please help me out how can i extract "MjE2LDI1OA== "  from the message into field called "entitelement"

Comment: if you can post rest of your grok i will be able to help